# What career level should I expect after career change?

Tags: software-industry, salary, career-switch, software-development

I am currently a 4th year part time student (computer science major, information assurance focus) at a local university and full time engineer in the Phoenix area.  My plan is to graduate next fall then make a career change into the IT arena, specifically cyber/network/IT security engineering.

I've been browsing around the job market for the last year and have noticed a common theme, almost everyone wants at least three years direct experience and certs.  The "entry level" jobs are...not well paid to say the least and even those prefer certifications.

I've been a manufacturing engineer with a large aerospace company for the past three years and had hoped the *engineer* bullet on my resume would help bridge the experience gap, but, so far, it's not looking promising.

Is it worth it to start going after low level certifications (CompTIA Security+, CEH, etc.)?  They can be quite pricey and I'd hate to throw money away.

Basically, what training and/or certs will help bridge the *experience* gap to help land a decent job after graduation? When I say "decent" I mean at least what I make now (in the 65k annually ballpark).  Is that possible or did I drastically overestimate my future value in the market when I decided to make this career change?

Thank you.

Comment: Your title says "after graduation" but I think you maybe should write "after career change"

Comment: Career advice is off topic, opinion based doubly so, voting to close.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager, changed to more direct question

Comment: @corporateWhore - "Basically, what training and/or certs" is still career advice.  A good question here should say what YOU want to do about your situation, and people can respond on that.  Saying "what do I do", or "what courses/certs" is a bad fit, people will have wildly opposing views, and it's specific to you, we want an answer that others can apply in a similar situation.

Comment: Um, ok.  I really don't know where else to go for advise.  The professors at school won't give me "career advise", the career services counselors push us towards sponsor companies, I've browsed around the internet for a more appropriate forum but came up short.  I really don't have any idea what to do here, I just need advise.

Comment: @corporateWhore - looking at your question, to me it it primarily that your are an engineer, retraining in another field, and all jobs you look at are either low paid due to lack of relevant experience, or want relevant experience, and how can you bridge the gap to show that your are experienced, even if it's not exactly what they want.  I answered another question like that where a car mechanic was becoming a dev and I pointed them to where their experience is relevant to the new industry.  You want something similar (but not the same as it's then a duplicate).

Comment: @corporateWhore - I think this is the crux.  You say you have a bullet saying you are an engineer, but you need to show in your resume where your experience is relevant to the other role.  Frame it in terms of the destination job, don't show it and expect them to connect the dots, they don't have the time reading your resume, you need to show them.

Comment: @corporateWhore - look at this  http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13979/how-can-i-sell-a-blue-collar-technical-background-when-applying-for-white-collar/13982#13982

Comment: @corporateWhore - aerospace, you have experience in working in a team on mission critical sub systems in a quality-centric environment.  You have worked on real deliverable projects and are (likely) a certified engineer.  This should be more than enough to blow your graduate colleagues out the water.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager, that link is perfect, thank you.  I will absolutely follow it's advise.  The "job requirements" sections of most of the postings contain a laundry list of required skills and/or experience I don't have.  It's just intimidating.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yes, however, there are an equal amount of people that say they don't matter "if you're good". Seeing that I have no documented proof of my relative "goodness", I assume they could help in my situation.  Just curious what others had experienced.

Comment: I can see how you would think that. I got the job I have now by taking a free online course in blueprint reading and being good at translating my blue-collar work in the industry to my white-collar aspirations.  The problem is, this is a completely foreign industry to me, while I was successful at selling my self for a job I was (on paper) unqualified for inside an industry I know, I have no Idea how to do that an industry I do not know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An entry level IT position is going to pay significantly less than you are making now if you just go in as an IT worker.

There are several approaches to finding a way to mitigate this.

- Find a job for someone with **all** of your skills and experience in your current field.  Often, industry experience will bump up your asking price
- Volunteer.  Volunteer work is a resume booster in and of itself.  volunteering to get experience, doubly so.  Do IT security work for a local charity and get that under your belt so that you have professional references for your IT work as well as your current work.
- Move to an area where your skills are rare.  If you able to move to take a position, do so, but be mindful of cost of living as well as salary.

Comment: "Find a job for someone with all of your skills and experience in your current field. Often, industry experience will bump up your asking price"  The problem with that is my industry is dying, I want out of manufacturing all together.  I'll start looking for volunteer opportunities.  Thanks.

Comment: @corporateWhore Pick up a copy of "What color is my parachute", it also has excellent advice.  Don't be so sure that manufacturing is dead, or that your skills in it don't translate.

Comment: thanks, just ordered it.  I'm not saying my industry is dead, but being on the front lines for more than 10 years I can safely say it is most definitely on it's door.  I'm tired of being furloughed, going multiple years without raises (on a division level), systematically losing benefits, watching plants close here and open in (insert any low labor cost country).  I can't take it anymore.  I want out.